# looking for api for huobi.com for last price data

Tags: api

I'm looking for last price data from huobi.com.

Does anyone know where I can get data from an API for them?

Huobi is the largest Bitcoin exchange in China and I'm looking to add them to http://tradeli.st

Answer (score 2):

Huobi Market Data api (google translate)
https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?act=url&depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://www.huobi.com/help/index.php%3Fa%3Dmarket_help&usg=ALkJrhiklnKqkg1JZM-VE37fNP7csWAEww